# Is there a way not to repeat this sub query in select clause? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way **not** to repeat the subquery in the following query syntax?

As you see, I have the total calculation as final price AND individual parts in Select clause.

I'm using SQL Server.

```
SELECT        
    ItemPrice.ItemID, 
    COALESCE( ItemPrice.MetalPrice, 0 ) + COALESCE(
    (SELECT SUM( PartsPrice.PartPriceTotal )
     FROM PartsPrice
     WHERE ItemPrice.ItemID = PartsPrice.ItemID
     GROUP BY PartsPrice.ItemID), 0) AS FinalItemPrice,
    ItemPrice.MetalPrice,
    (SELECT SUM(PartsPrice.PartPriceTotal)
     FROM PartsPrice
     WHERE ItemPrice.ItemID = PartsPrice.ItemID
     GROUP BY PartsPrice.ItemID) AS PartTotalPrice
FROM
    ItemPrice 
WHERE
    ItemPrice.ItemID = '100456'
GROUP BY
    ItemPrice.MetalPrice, 
    ItemPrice.ItemID
```

Comment: At a first glance, I would suggest to use OUTER APPLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT        
    ItemPrice.ItemID, 
    COALESCE (ItemPrice.MetalPrice, 0) + COALESCE (t2.partpricetotal, 0) AS FinalItemPrice,
    ItemPrice.MetalPrice, 
    t2.PartTotalPrice
FROM ItemPrice 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ItemID, SUM(PartsPrice.PartPriceTotal) as PartPriceTotal FROM PartsPrice GROUP BY PartsPrice.ItemID) t2
        ON ItemPrice.ItemID = PartsPrice.ItemID
WHERE ItemPrice.ItemID = '100456'
```

Comment: @MatBailie I missed that. I have removed. Thing would have errored out anyhow. :(

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to use a subquery in your `FROM` clause using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT I.ItemID,
       COALESCE(I.MetalPrice, 0) + PT.Total AS FinalItemPrice,
       I.MetalPrice,
       PT.Total AS PartTotalPrice
FROM ItemPrice I
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(PP.PartPriceTotal) AS Total
                  FROM PartsPrice  PP
                  WHERE I.ItemID = PP.ItemID
                  GROUP BY PP.ItemID) PT
WHERE I.ItemID = '100456'
GROUP BY I.MetalPrice,
         I.ItemID;
```

However, it looks like you don't need to use subqueries at all, use proper aggregation and `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT I.ItemID,
       COALESCE(I.MetalPrice, 0) + SUM(PP.PartPriceTotal) AS FinalItemPrice,
       I.MetalPrice,
       SUM(PP.PartPriceTotal) AS PartTotalPrice
FROM ItemPrice I
     JOIN PartsPrice PP ON I.ItemID = PP.ItemID
WHERE I.ItemID = '100456'
GROUP BY I.MetalPrice,
         I.ItemID;
```

*Of course, both of these are untested in the absence of sample data. I've also assumed that every `ItemPrice` has a `PartPrice`. If it doesn't you'll need to instead use `OUTER APPLY` or `LEFT JOIN` respectively.*

Comment: These queries will not return the same results, you need `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY` or if using the join syntax you will need `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @M.Ali I was just adding in an assumption caveat for the OP as you sent that. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT        
      itp.ItemID
    , COALESCE(itp.MetalPrice, 0) + COALESCE( SUM(pp.PartPriceTotal) , 0) AS FinalItemPrice
    , itp.MetalPrice
    , SUM(pp.PartPriceTotal)    AS PartTotalPrice
FROM ItemPrice itp
LEFT JOIN PartsPrice pp ON itp.ItemID = pp.ItemID 
WHERE itp.ItemID = '100456'
GROUP BY itp.MetalPrice, itp.ItemID
```

Comment: It could be my data but I get the double total amount. ($200 instead of $100) That's the reason I went to subquery path rather than join. I tried SUM Distinct but didn't give me the results I needed. Any idea?

Comment: Also, I have another table that I have to join and include in the SUM. It could be the cause of doubling the total. I just wanted to make the example simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use an inner subquery (in the `FROM` clause). Generally you shouldn't have subqueries in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT        
    ItemPrice.ItemID, 
    COALESCE( ItemPrice.MetalPrice, 0 ) + COALESCE( sq.PartPriceTotal, 0 ) AS FinalItemPrice,
    ItemPrice.MetalPrice,
    COALESCE( sq.PartPriceTotal, 0 ) AS PartTotalPrice
FROM
    ItemPrice
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            PartsPrice.ItemID,
            SUM( PartsPrice.PartPriceTotal )
        FROM
            PartsPrice
        GROUP BY
            PartsPrice.ItemID
    ) AS sq ON ItemPrice.ItemID = sq.ItemID
WHERE
    ItemPrice.ItemID = '100456'
GROUP BY
    ItemPrice.MetalPrice, 
    ItemPrice.ItemID
```